# Returning query results in graph format

Tags: c#, neo4j, neo4jclient

Is it possible to return the results of a cypher query executed via neo4jclient as two simple lists of nodes and relationships?

I notice from the neo4j documentation that results can be returned in [graph format](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html#rest-api-return-results-in-graph-format), but I'm not sure if this has been implemented in neo4jclient; if not can anyone give me some guidance on how to achieve this?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can just use a simple WebRequest to access the API yourself, it's pretty easy, see:

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/rest-api-transactional.html#rest-api-begin-and-commit-a-transaction-in-one-request

Comment: Thanks Michael. I've done as you suggested and called the API directly. I've also used your Cy2Neo code as guidance in reformatting the results from the API call.